# PgAdmin 4 - How to connect to database via ssh tunnel as posgres when its password is empty?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect to a Postgres database at my DigitalOcean instance via PgAdmin 4.

I create an SSH tunnel as root, provide the PgAdmin with my identify file. I want to login into database as postgres user which doesn't have a password.

So PgAdmin doesn't let me log in and requires the password for the postgres user.

Does user postgres have to have a password if I want to connect via SSH tunnel? Is it possible? And what should I do in order to connect?

[image: step1-general]
[[image: step2-connection]
[image: step3-ssh-tunnel]

Comment: What error are you getting? Usually a postgres password is ignored if not needed.  Are you complaining about the database password, or the "identify file" password?

Comment: About the database password. When I work with psql through a console, it doesn't require me to enter postgres password.

Comment: psql (by default) tries to connect without a password, and if rejected for want of a password it then asks for a password and tries again.  That would be awkward to do in a GUI.  If you use `psql -W`, it will ask for a password, and then ignore it if not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Does user postgres have to have a password if I want to connect via SSH tunnel? Is it possible? And what should I do in order to connect?*

Generally it does.

Your SSH tunnel is configured so that the remote SSH server connects to PostgreSQL through a TCP connection to `localhost`. And generally, a default `pg_hba.conf` maps this type of connection to the `md5` authentication scheme, for which a password is required. Otherwise any user with a shell account could connect to PostgreSQL, which would be wrong as a default configuration.

The more common way to use PostgreSQL through a SSH tunnel is to set a password to the PostgreSQL databases accounts that you need to connect to. Use the `\password` command inside `psql` or the `ALTER USER` SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks! I've created a separate user with a password and now I can connect to the DB.