# PgAdmin 4 - How to connect to database using unix socket via ssh tunnel?

Tags: postgresql, connectivity, pgadmin-4

Even though it might sound related to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264302/pgadmin-4-how-to-connect-to-database-via-ssh-tunnel-as-posgres-when-its-passwo), it isn't, because I'm intreseted in the use of unix sockets instead of TCP/IP ones.

However, I am unable to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database using unix sockets and an ssh tunnel with pgAdmin4. pgAdmin always claims a refused connection by the server and asks for a password, which makes me wonder. When sshing into the server and using psql a connection can be made just flawlessly using the unix socket (/var/run/postgresql). Is there anything special that needs to be set to allow such a setup, or might this even be a bug in pgAdmin itself? I'd appreciate any ideas to solve this problem without having to resort on TCP/IP connections on the remote side.

I also post some screens from my current config:

[image: connection tab]

[image: ssh tunnel tab]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should work fine with the correct `ssh` command.

To forward from a local Unix socket to a remote one runs

```bash
ssh -L /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5555:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 -N laurenz@dbserver
```

Then you would use host `/tmp` and port 5555 to connect.

To forward a local TCP socket to a remote Unix socket, run:

```bash
ssh -L 5555:/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 -N laurenz@dbserver
```

Then you would use host `127.0.0.1` and port 5555 to connect.

Comment: Where comes that limitation from? Doesn't a ssh tunnel work similar to a fully fledged ssh session?

Comment: Oops. I researched and saw that I was wrong. Answer updated.

Comment: It looks like my assumption about ssh tunnel beeing a fully fledged session was wrong too. Thank you for the update, this seems to be a very simple solution and might work until pgAdmin adds in native support for it.

Comment: Accepted, works flawlessly :)